# How can I embed a single Power BI Tile or Visualisation instead of a Report using Power BI Embedded?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We want to embed single visualisations into web pages from Power BI Embedded.

Other questions/answers on Stack Overflow seem to relate to embedding a Tile using the Power BI Service (PBIS), which is different to Power BI Embedded (PBIE). We definitely need PBIE as we will be serving reports to third parties who won't have licenses.

We want to build web reports produced by analysts (which are often much more than Power BI reports), and want to include key Visualisations alongside supporting text so that the insights are supported by an interactive chart/graph, and the visualisation is given context by the supporting text.

Ie. we want to tell a story in the report, and pick useful visualisations to support the story as it unfolds. Specifically we want to avoid embedding the entire report with all its pages lumped together in one spot on the webpage.

Anyone tackled this before?

Comment: What have you tried? Have gone through the 'get started guide?' https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-get-started/. This site is really for specific technical questions

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, Sounds like a perfectly valid question to me. The article does not address OPs specific problem.

Comment: @JaredPritchard, you might want to look/ask on the [official forums](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/bd-p/Developer). Regarding your problem, you could place your "story text" in the report itself - for examle using static text/image objects. Or you could have a report with a single tab, single visualization, and reduce its frame size to desired.

Comment: You're right - the sample here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-get-started-sample/ only shows embedding a report. Thew API here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powerbi.api.v1.aspx only has classes for reports, not tiles. It doesn't look like the API supports it.

Comment: Power BI has its limits, and if your report goes to any level of complexity it may not be worth trying to tie it all in. If this is a non interactive storyboard dynamic in its nature, take the practical approach and take a screenshot.

Comment: I'd like to add that many PowerBI visuals are using D3 engine under the hood, so might be worth looking into using a [D3 visualisation](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery) instead.

Comment: Cheers. I've asked on the forum & voted for a related Power BI "Idea", but it looks like it's not currently feasible. Thanks all for your help. Forum question: http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/How-can-I-embed-a-single-Power-BI-Tile-or-Visualisation-instead/m-p/98593/highlight/false#M3458

Related Power BI "Idea": https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/13480185-use-power-bi-embedded-with-dashboards-and-tile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not appear to be feasible, currently.

Some workaround ideas are included as comments to the question above (thanks @user5226582 & @Nick.McDermaid).

I've created a post on the Power BI forum to tease out some more thoughts, one post provided some basic workarounds: http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/How-can-I-embed-a-single-Power-BI-Tile-or-Visualisation-instead/m-p/98593/highlight/false#M3458

I've also voted for a Power BI "Idea" (a feature request). If others want the same feature, pop over & throw some votes against: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/13480185-use-power-bi-embedded-with-dashboards-and-tile